# Visual C++ can't find "Windows types" like PVOID, DWORD, ULONG, etc

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Windows can't seem to find any of these types, and I'm completely at a loss for what to do. The things I've found on MSDN seem to suggest that they're included by default, but they haven't worked in Native programs or CLR programs.

The specific errors I'm getting are:

`"<Project Name>.cpp(10): error C2065: 'PVOID' : undeclared identifier`

`"<Project Name>.cpp(10): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'varname'`

`"<Project Name>.cpp(10): error C2065: 'varname' : undeclared identifier`

How can I make Visual C++ recognize these types?

Comment: i think you should include <windows.h> if you haven't already done so

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You will need to include `windows.h`. Add this line at the top of your source file:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it. The code I'm working with didn't even mention it.

Comment: Note that you can't do this in an MFC app: `#error WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>`. This is implicitly included through the default `stdafx.h`.

Comment: I am working on Visual Studio C++ Console Application and I have to add both header files. `stdafx.h` and `<windows.h>`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include a header file to define these types.  Double-check the documentation or samples that you got the type names from to see what headers to include.

Comment: The samples didn't even mention windows.h, even though they have PVOIDs and ULONGs strewn about everywhere... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You have to include the Windows headers. The Windows headers are included in the default auto-generated projects- most of them. If you started an empty project instead, you won't have them included by default.