# how to compile c program on linux that runs on windows

Tags: c, linux, java-native-interface

I have got a project that is using jni to connect java wrapper and C code. It was developed by somebody else. I compiled the c code as a dynamic library in netbeans using mingw on windows and it works fine. Now I am trying to do the same in ubuntu. But when I open a header files in netbeans it underlines the following:

```
typedef PVOID FT_HANDLE;
typedef ULONG FT_STATUS;
```

and it says Unable to resolve identifier PVOID and the same for ULONG
Also getting several other errors "unable to resolve identifier".

When I build the proejct I get the following erros:
http://pastebin.com/hPrTJwxF

I am new to C. I have always programmed in Java. Any hints on that?

Comment: What do you find when you google these identifiers?

Comment: Perhaps the C library uses win32 functionality, and perhaps also MSVC compiler specific features. In that case you need to port the library to linux/posix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not standard C types, but it should ve trivial to #define your own replacements on Linux. See also [Visual C++ can't find "Windows types" like PVOID, DWORD, ULONG, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943865/visual-c-cant-find-windows-types-like-pvoid-dword-ulong-etc)

I would expect the following to work, but I have no means to test.

```
#define PVOID void *
#define ULONG unsigned long
```